# setting selected date into textview in android

Tags: android, date, calendar

I have calendar in my app. By clicking any of the date an activity will open with several edittext and one textview at the top right corner. I dont know how to set clicked date (say 12-Nov-2015) into the texview. Can anyone help me?

Also I need help to change color for the clicked date. Thanks

Comment: What technology / language are you using.  We'll need much more information to be able to assist with this

Comment: Please show your approach and where you got stuck. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I need to select a date in calendar and I want that date in a separate string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use setOnDateChangeListener like this:

`calendarview.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth, 0).show();
            }
        });`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here i want to get the clicked date in a string. I dont know what kind of code to use in place of Toast.

Comment: I have my customized calendar,which means i not using calendarview in my xml. Help me to solve this.